# Displaying Text inside QProgressBar

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am attempting to display a text inside a QprogressBar but nothing is being displayed.

Here is what I am doing:

```
ui.progressBar->setMaximum(0);
ui.progressBar->setMinimum(0);

ui.progressBar->setTextVisible(true);
ui.progressBar->setFormat("Hello World");
```

Any suggestions why nothing is being displayed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are using a busy indicator. This is what happens when both minimum and maximum are set to 0.

There are a few bug reports about this which are unresolved. Like [this](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-74) and [this](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-16260). These are pretty old though.